# How to get DataTable records in to list using lambda expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In given code I have written lambda expression but it shows an error that -- Can't convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

```
        EmployeeDataOperation emp = new EmployeeDataOperation(); //Class to perform CRUD operation.

        List<EmployeeProp> data = new List<EmployeeProp>();

        dt = emp.getEmployeeData();//return datatable with records.

        //I want to use lambda expression to use Datatable data as a list
        data = (from a in dt
                select new EmployeeProp { Name = a.Name, Email = a.Email }).ToList();
        //error near select

        return View(data);
```

Comment: here I have mentioned that I want to use lamda expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use either `.Field` linq extension or index/columnname (ex row["columnname"] to access values from a `DataRow`. I suggest using `Field` extension as it even handle `nullable` types.

```
data  = dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Select(row=>  new EmployeeProp ()
   {
       Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
       Email = row.Field<string>("Email ") 
       // Other properties....      
   })
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myData = (from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
               select new EmployeeProp { 
                   Name = a.Field<string>("Name"), 
                   Email = a.Field<string>("Email") 
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: I just want to try, otherwise, I am using entity framework which will return DbSet<> and easily convert into a list.

Comment: I missed that you had new EmployeeProp {}. So it would be a List<EmployeeProp>. Yes, a DbSet would be much cleaner and easier, doesn't need this cumbersome string syntax and provides intellisense on fields. If the source is something like MS SQL, MySQL, Sqlite ... then you might as well use Linq To SQL too instead of Linq to EF.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too, make EmployeeProp() object

```
data = (from a in dt
                select new EmployeeProp() { Name = a.Name, Email = a.Email }).ToList();
```